# Electron build strategy for web

Tags: webpack, electron

I am building an Electron application.
During the development I find it very productive to use the browser for implementation, debugging and testing.
However, when using any electron specific modules (remote.require, ipc etc), webpack fails to build the js.

What are the best practices for handling such cases?

I have 2 webpack configs, one for web and one for electron where I specify the target=electron, which works fine
It seems that the web version (that does not have this target), complaints for the electron modules

Below is a sample module where I conditionally try to require electron, but webpack tries to include it anyhow for the web

```
const isElectron = (function(){
    return navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Electron") == -1;
})();


export default {
    require: (module) => {
        if(isElectron){
            const electron = require("electron");
            return electron.remote.require(module);
        }
        return require(module);
    }
}
```

I even added

However, when webpack runs I get

```
ERROR in ./~/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs'
```

which disappears if I remove the electron require

Anyone else with such a case?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you don't have access to `fs` from the *renderer*, only from *main*. The way I got around this was to define `fs`in my main process and use the shared object to make it accessible:

`// main
global.sharedObject = {
    cwd: __dirname,
    appDir: app.getPath('userData')
};`

and

`// renderer
console.log(electron.remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').cwd);`

Depending on your case, you might e.g.:

- make use of something like `electron-json-storage`
- define all your paths in main and access them via shared object
- use IPC to call fs-related operations.

Comment: Hi. I have opened a ticket for this here. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3376#issuecomment-267376624

Comment: This helped me with a issue with webpack and puppeteer. :D Learned a lot. Thanks.